# Querying Properties Array mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I am trying to get building by its id:

I have a collection called buildings:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b3b1cc79c23061e4d4634e4"),
    "buildings" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 0,
            "name" : "Farm",
            "description" : "Best farm of all times",
            "img" : "http://i.hizliresim.com/yq5g57.png",
            "wood" : "50",
            "stone" : "10"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "Storage",
            "description" : "Store your resources.",
            "img" : "http://i.hizliresim.com/yq5g47.png",
            "wood" : "100",
            "stone" : "200"
        }
    ]
}
```

For example with id 0,i would like to get data of Farm.

I tried this:
db.getCollection('buildings').find({"buildings.id":0})

not working

sample output :

```
{
                "id" : 0,
                "name" : "Farm",
                "description" : "Best farm of all times",
                "img" : "http://i.hizliresim.com/yq5g57.png",
                "wood" : "50",
                "stone" : "10"
            }
```

Tried:

```
var data = Buildings.find({},{buildings:{$elemMatch:{id:0}}}).fetch();
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

result:(all data)

```
[{"_id":{"_str":"5b3b1cc79c23061e4d4634e4"},"buildings":[{"id":0,"name":"Farm","description":"Best farm of all times","img":"http://i.hizliresim.com/yq5g57.png","wood":"50","stone":"10"},{"id":1,"name":"Storage","description":"Store your resources.","img":"http://i.hizliresim.com/yq5g47.png","wood":"100","stone":"200"}]}]
```

Comment: you have put extra curly braces... Remove them... Try this `db.collection.find({
  "buildings.id": 0
})`

Comment: i did it gave me all data  json.stringfy result : [{"_id":{"_str":"5b3b1cc79c23061e4d4634e4"},"buildings":[{"id":0,"name":"Farm","description":"Best farm of all times","img":"http://i.hizliresim.com/yq5g57.png","wood":"50","stone":"10"},{"id":1,"name":"Storage","description":"Store your resources.","img":"http://i.hizliresim.com/yq5g47.png","wood":"100","stone":"200"}]}]

Comment: so what you want?

Comment: just "id":0 s data in this case {
            "id" : 0,
            "name" : "Farm",
            "description" : "Best farm of all times",
            "img" : "http://i.hizliresim.com/yq5g57.png",
            "wood" : "50",
            "stone" : "10"
        },

Comment: Use elemmatch(projection). more [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#zipcode-search) i.e `db.getCollection('buildings').find({},{buildings:{$elemMatch:{id:0}}})`

Comment: tried veerams not working i got again all data

Comment: Can I see you query ?

Comment: edited first post

Comment: Can you try the query in shell ? May be meteor has different syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) aggregation to exclude the unwanted elements from the array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "buildings.id": 0 }},
  { "$project": {
    "shapes": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        { "$filter": {
          "input": "$buildings",
          "as": "building",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [
              "$$building.id",
              0
            ]
          }
        }},
        0
      ]
    },
    "_id": 0
  }}
])
```

Comment: then please post the sample output you want from the collection you have posted

Answer (score 1):

Try for this

```
db.getCollection("collectionName").find({buildings: {"$elemMatch": {"id" : "0"}}})
```

Here the find method will look(cursor) for the data with buildings and id=0

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.find({
    buildings: {
        $elemMatch: {
            id: 0
        }
    }
}, {
    'buildings.$': 1
})
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.